# Создание внешних стилей CSS и внешних скриптов

Tags: javascript, html, css

Здравствуйте есть три файла:

CW.html с кодом:

```
<html>

<head>
    <meta charset = "utf-8">
    <title>Таблиця имен</title>
    <script>src = "tablescript.js"</script>
</head>

<body></body>

</html>
```

tablestyle.css с кодом:

```
 table {
         width: 50%;
         border: 3px solid black;
         border-collapse: collapse;
         margin: auto;
 }
 td, th {
         padding: 2px;
         border: solid black;
 }
 th {
     background: deepskyblue;
 }
 .center {
          text-align: center;
 }
 tbody tr:hover {
                 background: cyan;
 }
```

и tablescript с кодом:

```
function randomValue(min, max) {
return Math.floor(Math.random() * (max - min + 1) + min);
}

function tableMaker() { 
amount = +prompt("Ввеите кол-во полей:");

var wnd = window.open('#','_blank');

wnd.document.write ('<html>');
wnd.document.write ('<head>');
wnd.document.write ('<title></title>');
wnd.document.write ('<link rel = "stylesheet" type = "text/css" href= "tablestyle.css">'); 
wnd.document.write ('</head>');
wnd.document.write ('<body>');

wnd.document.write ('<p align = "center" style = "font-size: 30px">Таблица персональных даных </p>');
wnd.document.write ('<table>');
wnd.document.writeln('<tr> <th>№<\/th><th>Ф.И.О.<\/th><th>Год рождения<\/th><th>Вес<\/th> <\/tr>');
for (var i = 0; i < amount; i++) {
   var name = prompt("Введите Ф.И.О." + (i + 1) +" - го человека:");
   if (name.trim() == "") {
   do {
       name =  prompt("Вы ничего не ввели. Попробуйте, еще раз:")
   } while (name.trim() == "");
   }
wnd.document.writeln('<tr class = "center">');
wnd.document.writeln('<td>' + (i + 1) + '<\/td>');
wnd.document.writeln('<td>' + name + '<\/td>');
wnd.document.writeln('<td>' + randomValue(1900, 2016) + '<\/td>');
wnd.document.writeln('<td>' + randomValue(3, 150) + '<\/td>');
wnd.document.writeln('<\/tr>');     
}
wnd.document.write ('</table>');
wnd.document.write ('</body>');
wnd.document.write ('</html>');
}
```

Єто моя первая работа с JavaScript и CSS, скажите,пожалуйста, что не так.

Comment: А что с этим не так?

Comment: вообще не работает

Comment: вернее ничего не показывает

Comment: это все потому, что src - это атрибут должен быть, а не внутренность

Comment: а в консоли ошибок нету

Comment: @Grundy, а на какой его менять?

Comment: Потому что формально это рабочий код. 
Попробуйте `<script src="tablescript.js"></script>`

Comment: что значит на какой? :-) его не надо менять, его надо вынести _из_ тега скрипт и сделать атрибутом тега скрипт

Comment: все равно ничего

Comment: Сам код работает если кинуть скрипт в файл с html, и построение таблици не делать в функцией . Но хотелось бы,чтобы таблицу строила функция, а скрипт был именно  внешним

Comment: перепишите вызов скрипта в `head`, как вам указали выше, и добавьте вызов вашей функции в конец скрипта: а-ля `tableMaker();`

Answer (score 3, accepted):

Нужно исправить два пункта:

```html
<html>

<head>
    <meta charset = "utf-8">
    <title>Таблиця имен</title>
    
    <!-- Первая правка -->
    <script src="tablescript.js"></script>
</head>

      <!-- Вторая правка -->
<body onload="tableMaker()">
    
</body>

</html>
```

Comment: `onload` не требуется. Достаточно просто вызвать.

Comment: почему этого не стоит делать?

Comment: код работает с ним

Comment: Не принципиально, важно только что нужно вызвать функцию. Можно и к кнопке привязать или к другой логике.

Comment: @AkaInq, спасибо за ваше внимание

Answer (score 0):

Вам нужно вставить 2 простые строчки в блок `head`:

```
<link href="dir/tablestyle" rel="stylesheet"> //Отвечает за присоединение файла css

<script src="tablescript.js"></script> //Отвечает за присоединение файла js
```

`dir` отвечает за путь к файлу относительно вашего `index` файла

Comment: css файл в данном случае добавляется из javascript и используется в новом окне, откуда будет не доступен. по этому css добавлять не нужно.